# ITTM busy beaver function VS Rayo's function

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

It is known that both functions surpass the Busy Beaver function and $\Xi(n)$, but how do they compare with each other?

It seems that people thought I was confused with the definedness of Rayo's Function.

Edit: The whole of the problem comes because ITTM BB's grow faster than a theoretical ordinal that is the INFINITE SEQUENCE OF COMBINATIONS OF ORDINALS, each can have infinite size, that ordinal's ordinality is larger than $\beth_1$ (translated to ordinals), while Rayo's function can only take in a finite number of different symbols, each with finite length. Assuming this definition, $\mathrm{Rayo}(n) \lt \Sigma_\omega(n)$

But somehow this can be computed with infinite symbols or args.

Plus, in the [Googology Wiki](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/Googology_Wiki), it is unknown how they compare with each.

Comment: These aren't simply 'fast growing functions'. Rayo's function, in particular, can depend a lot on your ambient set theory; it isn't definable in ZFC alone. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199190/the-first-few-values-of-rayos-function for more on this.

Comment: The reason I was asking was to specifically say "how do you put a function that grows faster than the supreme of all eventually writable ordinals", rayo's function only takes a finite amount of symbols, I cannot just do [n,n,n,...,n,n] E x1, where E denotes "inside of" in first order logic/set theory and then compute that in a finite amount of symbols.

Comment: I have replaced 'beth-1' with $\beth_1$, since this is the only thing I know of (or could find on related GW pages) that fits. If this is not correct, please update the question.

Comment: @David Roberts thank you for making it more understandable for some other readers.

Comment: What does it mean for a *function* to grow faster than an *ordinal*? Are you referring to some sort of fast-growing hierarchy? Also, how exactly are you defining the ITTM BB function? The only definitions I can think of are obviously expressible in $V$, but maybe you have something else in mind.

Comment: I'm more worried about the fact, AFAIK, the cardinal value (and hence the ordinal) of $\beth_1$ is independent of ZFC. So I must be misunderstanding what that sentence is getting at.

Comment: You seem to have [edited](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/377625/2) your post to respond to what people might have thought, but it makes the post a bit strange, since you appear to be responding to concerns that aren't obviously voiced here.  Were you responding to @NoahSchweber's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/377628)?  If so, then the place to do so is a comment in that answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Busy Beaver function for ITTMs is definable in $V$ (the universe of sets), whereas Rayo's function dominates every $V$-definable function. So Rayo's function is unspeakably larger.

OK, there is a subtlety here. When we define Rayo's function, we use a truth predicate for the whole universe of sets. This isn't something we can define unless we're working in a richer theoretical framework than mere set theory - some appropriate *class theory* is needed. So the precise statement of the above fact is that such an appropriate class theory proves that Rayo's function dominates every $V$-definable function, and in particular is much faster than the ITTM-Busy Beaver function.

(Specifically, if memory serves the class theory $\mathsf{MK}$ is the right theory to work with: it's the natural class theory which proves that Rayo's function actually exists. Meanwhile the weaker class theory $\mathsf{NBG}$ can't prove that Rayo's function exists, but can prove that **if** it exists it dominates the ITTM-Busy Beaver function.)

Comment: How do you define an ITTM BB (which dominates ordinals reaching omega-1 using the continuum hypothesis) within the language of V, such that the length to define that function (ITTM BB's) is finite and can eventually dominate that function itself to with n is less than aleph-0?

Comment: @ygtfrew The essence of the definition is: ITTM-BB(n) is the number m satisfying the following statement: m is the largest k such that there exists an ITTM M with n states (which is encoded via its transition function) and an ordinal-indexed sequence of configurations which starts with the empty tape, ends in a configuration with exactly k 1s on the tape, and the sequence of configurations follows M's transition function and behaves well at limit steps. Formally writing this in the language of set theory would be an awful chore, but nothing that couldn't be done

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for explaining it exactly to me, since I think the googology wiki messed up my definition using ITTM ordinals.

Comment: @Wojowu: "behaves well at limit steps" -- what does it mean? How can an ITTM behave badly at limit steps?

Comment: @lyricallywicked It's not about the ITTM behaving well, it's about the computation history following the limit rule - specifically, at every limit stage the machine should enter the limit state and every cell should hold the value which is limsup of its values at earlier times.